# Transforming PointCloud topic to LaserScan topic

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, perception-pcl, gazebo-ros-openni-kinect, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I have been trying to convert a PointCloud topic which is generated by gazebo_ros_openni_kinect into LaserScan topic. The gazebo plugin publishes a simulated openni output to /cam3d/depth/points topic, and it seems to work correctly.

I was able to inspect the code that pcl_to_scan package has, and managed to rebuilt it into a standalone working source file using the ros kinect publisher tutorials and disabling dynamic reconfigure. The file publishes some laser data. However, the laser data seems to decrease over time, and when it reaches 0, it starts over.

**For example, when the data is first published: (Range values are around 0.8)**

> ```
> > angle_min: -1.57079637051 angle_max:
> > 1.57079637051 angle_increment: 0.0174532923847 time_increment: 0.0 scan_time: 0.0333333350718 range_min:
> > 0.10000000149 range_max: 10.0 ranges: [0.8371890783309937,
> > 0.8371157646179199, 0.8371505737304688, 0.841155469417572, 0.8416852355003357, 0.8424785137176514, 0.7871079444885254, 0.7877516150474548, 0.7892191410064697, 0.7909254431724548, 0.7928680777549744, 0.7950447797775269, 0.7974526882171631, 0.8000890612602234, 0.8029510378837585, 0.8060353398323059, 0.8093387484550476, 0.8137710094451904, 0.8175548315048218, 0.8215464353561401, 0.8268224000930786, 0.831267774105072, 0.8370987176895142, 0.8419783115386963, 0.8483396172523499, 0.8549846410751343, 0.8604996800422668, 0.8676356673240662, 0.8750333786010742, 0.882685124874115, 0.892191469669342, 0.900374710559845, 0.9087872505187988, 0.9191746711730957, 0.9280658960342407, 0.939006507396698, 0.9502314925193787, 0.9617291688919067, 0.9734877347946167, 0.9875211715698242, 0.9998075366020203, 1.014427661895752, 1.0293407440185547, 1.0445315837860107, 1.0622141361236572, 1.0779519081115723, 1.0962239503860474, 1.1171224117279053, 1.1359834671020508, 1.157501220703125, 1.1817551851272583, 1.2038718461990356, 1.2287416458129883, 1.256429672241211, 1.2844353914260864, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0]
> ```

**And after a while, it is like this: (Range values are around 0.02)**

> ```
> > angle_min: -1.57079637051 angle_max:
> > 1.57079637051 angle_increment: 0.0174532923847 time_increment: 0.0 scan_time: 0.0333333350718 range_min:
> > 0.10000000149 range_max: 10.0 ranges: [0.11726024001836777,
> > 0.05766232684254646, 0.04177795350551605, 0.02987378090620041, 0.025909584015607834, 0.021949056535959244, 0.017994627356529236, 0.046077899634838104, 0.01405144389718771, 0.0584421269595623, 0.03429332748055458, 0.010132638737559319, 0.026504002511501312, 0.04287064075469971, 0.03901761397719383, 0.022650254890322685, 0.035191018134355545, 0.060264796018600464, 0.006283995695412159, 0.05273519456386566, 0.04019985720515251, 0.027660993859171867, 0.036499835550785065, 0.015129179693758488, 0.023996248841285706, 0.03286304697394371, 0.09480049461126328, 0.0381767563521862, 0.02931303158402443, 0.020446542650461197, 0.01158352755010128, 0.04898853227496147, 0.02588552236557007, 0.05444787070155144, 0.03138109669089317, 0.017083730548620224, 0.0369064100086689, 0.022636234760284424, 0.04800030216574669, 0.02820809744298458, 0.03378802165389061, 0.04495486989617348, 0.05611952021718025, 0.08399122208356857, 0.1616191416978836, 0.0028102879878133535, 0.08396531641483307, 0.05610218644142151, 0.044940974563360214, 0.033777572214603424, 0.028199369087815285, 0.047970641404390335, 0.022629227489233017, 0.03688358888030052, 0.017078444361686707, 0.03136168420314789, 0.054380614310503006, 0.02586950734257698, 0.048928000032901764, 0.011579941026866436, 0.020433885976672173, 0.029285836964845657, 0.03812955319881439, 0.09447945654392242, 0.03282240405678749, 0.02397397719323635, 0.01511981338262558, 0.036443427205085754, 0.027626775205135345, 0.040125325322151184, 0.05260495841503143, 0.006282049231231213, 0.06007887050509453, 0.03512575477361679, 0.022622225806117058, 0.03893321752548218, 0.04276470094919205, 0.026463015004992485, 0.01012636348605156, 0.034219127148389816, 0.05822576582431793, 0.014038392342627048, 0.04593560844659805, 0.017972351983189583, 0.021915104240179062, 0.025861503556370735, 0.029809128493070602, 0.041648901998996735, 0.05741326883435249, 0.11621594429016113, 0.11621594429016113, 0.05741326883435249, 0.041648901998996735, 0.029809124767780304, 0.025861501693725586, 0.021915104240179062, 0.017972351983189583, 0.045935604721307755, 0.014038392342627048, 0.05822575092315674, 0.03421912342309952, 0.01012636348605156, 0.026463011279702187, 0.04276468977332115, 0.03893321007490158, 0.02262222208082676, 0.035125747323036194, 0.060078851878643036, 0.006282049231231213, 0.05260493978857994, 0.04012531787157059, 0.027626771479845047, 0.03644341602921486, 0.015119810588657856, 0.023973971605300903, 0.032822392880916595, 11.0, 0.0381295420229435, 0.029285825788974762, 0.020433882251381874, 0.011579939164221287, 11.0, 0.025869499891996384, 11.0, 0.03136167302727699, 0.017078440636396408, 0.03688357397913933, 0.02262921817600727, 11.0, 0.02819935604929924, 0.03377755358815193, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 0.0028102879878133535, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 0.028208084404468536, 11.0, 0.02263622358441353, 11.0, 0.017083728685975075, 11.0, 11.0, 0.025885511189699173, 11.0, 0.011583525687456131, 0.02044653333723545, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 0.02399623766541481, 0.015129175037145615, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 0.006283994298428297, 11.0, 11.0, 0.02265024557709694, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 0.01013263687491417, 11.0, 11.0, 0.014051438309252262, 11.0, 0.01799461990594864, 0.021949047222733498, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0]
> ```

**Here is the code that I'm trying to work with:**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.h"
#include "nodelet/nodelet.h"

#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"

#include "pcl/point_cloud.h"
#include "pcl_ros/point_cloud.h"
#include "pcl/point_types.h"
#include "pcl/ros/conversions.h"

#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>

// Dynamic reconfigure includes.
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>

using namespace std;

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;

ros::Publisher pub_;
ros::Subscriber sub_;
ros::Publisher marker_pub;

void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& msg) 
{
  sensor_msgs::LaserScanPtr output(new sensor_msgs::LaserScan());

  ROS_INFO("Got cloud");
  //Copy Header
  output->header = msg->header;
  output->header.frame_id = "scan"; //output_frame_id_ 
  output->angle_min = -M_PI / 2; // Default: -M_PI / 6;
  output->angle_max = M_PI / 2; // Default: M_PI / 6;;
  output->angle_increment = M_PI / 180.0; // Default: M_PI / 180.0 / 2.0
  output->time_increment = 0.0;
  output->scan_time = 1.0 / 30.0;
  output->range_min = 0.1;
  output->range_max = 10.0;

  uint32_t ranges_size = std::ceil(
          (output->angle_max - output->angle_min)
                / output->angle_increment);
  output->ranges.assign(ranges_size, output->range_max + 1.0);

  //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
  //pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, cloud);

  visualization_msgs::Marker line_list;

  float min_z = 100;
  float max_z = -100;
  float min_y = 100;
  float max_y = -100;

  double max_height_ = 5; // Default: 5
  double min_height_ = 0; // Default: 0


  BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, msg->points){

      float x = pt.x;
      float y = pt.y;
      float z = pt.z;

      if (z < min_z)
          min_z = z;
      if (z > max_z)
          max_z = z;

      if (y < min_y)
          min_y = y;
      if (y > max_y)
          max_y = y;

      if (std::isnan(x) || std::isnan(y) || std::isnan(z)) {
          ROS_INFO("rejected for nan in point(%f, %f, %f)\n", x, y, z);
          continue;
      }

      if (z > max_height_ || z < min_height_) { 
          ROS_INFO("rejected for height %f not in range (%f, %f)\n", z, min_height_, max_height_);
          continue;
      }
      double angle = atan2(y, x);
      if (angle < output->angle_min || angle > output->angle_max) {
          ROS_INFO("rejected for angle %f not in range (%f, %f)\n",
                  angle, output->angle_min, output->angle_max);
          continue;
      }

      int index = (angle - output->angle_min) / output->angle_increment;
      //    NODELET_INFO("index xyz( %f %f %f) angle %f index %d", x, y, z, angle, index);
      double range_sq = y * y + x * x;
      if (output->ranges[index] * output->ranges[index] > range_sq)
          output->ranges[index] = sqrt(range_sq);

      ROS_INFO("Y: %f %f, Z: %f %f", min_y, max_y, min_z, max_z);

      line_list.header = msg->header;
      line_list.header.frame_id = output->header.frame_id;
      line_list.ns = "points_and_lines";
      line_list.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
      line_list.pose.orientation.w = 0.0; // Default: 1.0  
      line_list.id = 0;

      line_list.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::LINE_LIST;

      line_list.scale.x = 0.1;
      //    line_list.color.r = 1.0;
      line_list.color.a = 1.0;

      // Create the vertices for the points and lines
      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ranges_size; ++i) {
          float rng = output->ranges[i];
          float a = output->angle_min + i * output->angle_increment;
          float x = rng * cos(a);
          float y = rng * sin(a);

          geometry_msgs::Point p;
          std_msgs::ColorRGBA col;
          p.x = x;
          p.y = y;
          p.z = min_height_;

          col.g = rng / (output->range_max);
          col.r = 1.0 - col.g;
          line_list.colors.push_back(col);
          line_list.colors.push_back(col);

          // The line list needs two points for each line
          line_list.points.push_back(p);
          p.z = max_height_;
          line_list.points.push_back(p);
      }

      marker_pub.publish(line_list);
      pub_.publish(output);
  }

}

    double min_height_, max_height_;
    int32_t u_min_, u_max_;
    std::string output_frame_id_;
    bool dynamic_set;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "sub_pcl");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("/cam3d/depth/points", 1, callback);

  pub_ = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> ("/scan", 10); 
  marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> (
                "visualization_marker", 10);

  ros::spin();
}
```

I'm really stuck and don't know why the range values decreases. I suspect that it might have something to do with poorly configured TF, but I don't know how to change these parameters in order to correct the code. Any help will be greately appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73186/transforming-pointcloud-topic-to-laserscan-topic/) by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why don't you just do something like this?

```
<launch>

<!-- Do whatever you need to do to publish /cam3d/depth/points -->



<!-- nodelet manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

  
<!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="max_rate" value="20.0"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/cam3d/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

<!-- Fake Laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="fake_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/your_frame_id"/>
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.15"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <param name="max_height" value="0.15"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Fake Laser (narrow one, for localization -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="my_laser_narrow" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/your_frame_id"/>
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.025"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <param name="max_height" value="0.025"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="/narrow_scan"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Although implementing your own version of pcl_to_scan might be a good programming exercise, I don't see why you need to do it that way, when you can just play with the tools provided by ROS. Just an opinion, I might have misunderstood your purpose.
Cheers

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-15**:
I tried doing this but I cant get it working. Maybe I need some groundwork for it. How do I install the dependencies to use this launch file? You actually understood my purpose. I need to convert a pcl topic to laserscan. But can't use launch files that use openni, because I'm simulating openni with gazebo_ros_openni_kinect.

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-15**:
Okay, here is the error to the launch file that you've provided. I really need your help:

[ERROR] [1376620187.308327378, 19.779000000]: Failed to load nodelet [/fake_laser] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image kobuki_auto_docking/AutoDockingNodelet kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet kobuki_controller_tutorial/BumpBlinkControllerNodelet kobuki_node/KobukiNodelet kobuki_safety_controller/SafetyControllerNodelet nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/ExtractInd

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-15**:
I downloaded nodelet package and catkinized it, now I have this error:
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-08-15**:
which version of ros are you using? if you use groovy you can install the nodelet package with: sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-nodelet (but I think it should be already installed by default)

I am looking into which package provides the nodelet pointcloud_to_laserscan, I will let you know asap

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-16**:
I'm using groovy. I have tried installing from source and package, Still can't get it working. What should I do?

**Comment by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on 2013-08-23**:
This actually works. My package name and tf turned out to be faulty, and now they all are corrected. Accept my delayed gratitude.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-28**:
@mozcelikors when i run launch file, i am getting same error. How did you solve it ?

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-07-24**:
please tell me how to convert laserscan to pointcloud with urg04lx laser scanner . Everyone tells me laser_geometry but how???

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2018-06-10**:
Mekateng, this post can help you on converting laser scans into pointcloud: http://www.theconstructsim.com/merge-laser-scans-single-pointcloud/